# Can I send push messages over a web socket interface and is there a JavaScript SDK I can integrate?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

Want to be able to send push messages to a website and wondered if I can trigger them from journey builder.

Thinking I may need some kind of websocket gateway + SDK - anything in ExactTarget that could help here?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly things work in exact target, but if you can execute JavaScript, then have a look at Pusher or PubNub for real-time push notifications. They both have JavaScript libraries.

Comment: This looks like it might be helpful - but is this for mobile app delivery? http://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/push/postMessageAppSend.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe to do this you'll need to do some server-side programming.  I don't believe Journey Builder can communicate directly with your website.  You'll need to create a web app with a [web socket server](http://codular.com/node-web-sockets) and also create a [custom activity](https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node).

```
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});
wsServer.on('request', function(r){
    // Code here to run on connection
});
```

```
exports.execute = function( req, res ) {
    // Data from the req and put it in an array accessible to the main app.
    //console.log( req.body );
    activityUtils.logData( req );

    sendMessage(req,res);
};
```

Your JB interaction will listen for events.  When an event is fired (ie. user_likes_product_abc == true) your interaction will call your custom activity.  Your custom activities' "execute" function will then hit a route on your web app (/message/{sessionID}?t="10% off if you order in the next hour."). Your web app will then sync up the sessionID with users' connection and then push the message to the client.

I also wonder if you could use the [Collect product](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/web_and_mobile_analytics/core_components/collect/) as input for interaction's event. For anonymous users of your website, I'm thinking your server would need to provide a unique user id in the SetUserInfo script.